# Why is java program skipping my inner loop?

Tags: while-loop, nested-loops, do-while

Hello I'm a beginning programming Student and I am practicing using loops to validate input. Unfortunately, the loop works but skips the inner loop entirely... I get now error message or prompt...

Here is my code: [I BORROWED IT FROM AN ANSWER ON THIS SITE ABOUT VALIDATING INPUT SO I COULD TEST IT.]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidationTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            System.out.println("That's not a number!");
            sc.next(); // this is important!
        }  
        number = sc.nextInt();
       } while (number <= 0);
    System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + number);
}
}
```

Comment: I only get the error message if it is not a number but negatives make it repeat without any error message or prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop :

```
 while (!sc.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        System.out.println("That's not a number!");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }  
    number = sc.nextInt();
```

only check if your input is not a number, if you input -123, the function `!sc.hasNextInt()` is false so it'll skip the loop, if you want to check the number is negative, add this check after the assign number value:

```
 if(number <= 0 ){
     System.out.println("The number is negative!");
 }
```

You don't have to make another loop for checking the number is negative or not because of the first loop had it, and `do...while` loop will make sure you have to run the loop at least one time

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe the answer was so simple. >B-D

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop will be skipped if the condition (in parentheses after `while`) is false when the `while` loop is first executed.

You can use a debugger to step through the code to see what is going on.

If you do not know how to use a debugger, stop everything you are doing and do some Google searches or whatever you need to do to find out how to use one.

Answer (score 0):

your int number is NaN (not a number). Try setting it to -1, so you can enter the first loop. 
In second loop sc didn't ever scan for input it's only initialized.